# Unit test function that reads configuration file

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I am learning Golang and was working on an application that reads a yaml configuration file and loads its contents into a struct. I'm adding tests to the app, and was wondering if there is a way of no having to pass a real file to `ioutil.ReadFile` and instead mock its contents.
Let's say that the struct object of the configuration is something like:

```
type AppConfig struct {
    someConfig       string `yaml:"someConfig"`
    someOtherConfig  string `yaml:"someOtherConfig"`
}
```

And the function to read the configuration is:

```
func readConfig(filePath string) (*AppConfig, error) {

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conf := AppConfig{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &conf)
    if err != nil {
        return &AppConfig{}, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%#v\n", conf)

    return &conf, nil
}
```

Comment: Some options:  (1) Read an actual file from the `testdata` sub-directory (the Go tools ignore directories with this name). (2) Allow the test to mock the file system by modifying the application to work with a [io/fs](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs) file system (3) Split the function in to two functions where the function that does the parsing works with an `io.Reader`.  Test the second function.

Comment: The most common solution to this would be for `readConfig` to accept an `io.Reader` rather than a file path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would split the function into one that does the reading and one that does Unmarshalling into `conf`. Pass the result of the first function (the file contents) into the second. Then you can easily test the second function.

Another option would be to wrap `ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)` into a helper function and mock that function when testing `readConfig()`.

Comment: ioutil package gonna be deprecated if you using go 1.16

Comment: Thanks a lot @EricSchaefer

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easily by the use of interface and a little modification.

```
// Defining an interface so that functionality of 'readConfig()' can be mocked
type IReader interface{
    readConfig() ([]byte, error)
}

type reader struct{
    fileName string
}

// 'reader' implementing the Interface
// Function to read from actual file
func (r *reader) readConfig() ([]byte, error) {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(r.fileName)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return file, err
}
```

Modifying the original code to read and set config:

```
type AppConfig struct {
    someConfig       string `yaml:"someConfig"`
    someOtherConfig  string `yaml:"someOtherConfig"`
}

// Function takes the mentioned Interface as a parameter
func getConfig(reader IReader) (*AppConfig, error) {
    file, err :=reader.readConfig()

    conf := AppConfig{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &conf)
    if err != nil {
        return &AppConfig{}, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%#v\n", conf)

    return &conf, nil
}
```

And when you want to read using actual method:

```
func main() {
    reader := reader{fileName:"Actual File Name"}
    configVal, err := getConfig(&reader)
    fmt.Println("Values received from file: ", configVal, err)
}
```

Now, coming to testing the code:

```
type readerTest struct {
    fileName string
}

// 'readerTest' implementing the Interface
func (r *readerTest) readConfig() ([]byte, error) {
    // Prepare data you want to return without reading from the file
    return []byte{}, nil
}

func TestGetConfig() {
    testReader := readerTest{fileName:"Sample File Name"}
    configVal, err := getConfig(&testReader)
    fmt.Println("Write tests on values: ", configVal, err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rajvir